# Camera switch with ov7670 to output standard A/V signal - composite

Tags: arduino-uno

I've got 3 OV7670 cameras and would like to create a switch that outputs one of the cameras video as standard A/V out (I'm not sure the correct naming).

I found docs explaining how to use the cameras on the Arduino platform but I'm not sure how to output video signal - composite.

Comment: I think you mean `composite video`

Comment: *Three* cameras driven by *1* puny Arduino? Video is what you get when you read frames from the camera very quickly (at least 10 frames per second reasonably) and render those frames very quickly on some screen. You can't do either with an Arduino (Uno?) effectively, even if you'll be switching between them. Take a look at this though: https://github.com/ComputerNerd/ov7670-no-ram-arduino-uno

Comment: Thanks for comments, I've updated post and now looking at the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An arduino uno is way too slow to output composite video. If you want to generate a PAL video signal you can see [here](http://martin.hinner.info/vga/pal.html) the signal specification.

Most important, one line is output in 52us. If the line is 720px long (720x576 is the common resolution), then you will have to generate one pixel in 72ns. This means that

1. you will need a very fast DAC (a flash one)
2. you will need a VERY fast microcontroller. If you have a 160MHz uC you will have to send one output byte every 11 clock cycles, which means that you will barely be able to do any more processing.

Result: it is practically unfeasable. I suggest you, if you want to use it, to look for hardware encoders. But... Probably you will need some faster processing units: maybe a raspberry PI, which already have an hardware encoder...